# android app supporting samall and large screen (tablet and phone)

Tags: android-layout, android, multiscreen

I've made android application for my USB Relay Boards. Actually boards are connected to PC/OpenWRT router via USB and then server app takes hold of everything. So more or less, android is just communicating with my custom app on the server side.

The problem i hava is with layout. You can see my current app on this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73DhEVNqW3Y

Its not bad, but not best practices also.

The container for the views is full screen gallery, with custom adapter.

Ui is a pain here, cause I don't know how many boards i want to connect here. So my app ask the server for board count, and then adds boars view to the gallery.

I have a question here. How would you do it in best practice way?

How to interface it with large screens? At this point i think, that for tablets the best option is tu put 3 views on landscape view next to each other. If there are more than 3 boards user can scroll left or right. If 2 or 1, just center the view.

I know that I should not use gallery like this. What i should use to achieve that kind of functionality (iphone style left, right slide with aligned on full view) i best practice way?

Thanks for suggestions.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was really a stupid mistake.

When I pressed the button my app send a command, and received back the status of server. In the status packet my server sends, between others, count of the boards in connected to it. After receiving that value android was putting it in to Preference. On that preference I had a listener, witch was triggering and restarted the activity (cause it was thinking the count of board have been changed).

So its solved.